# Regex to capture groups and ignore last two characters where one is optional

Tags: java, regex

I need to capture two groups from an input string.  The values differ in structure as they come in.

The following are examples of the incoming strings:

`Comment = "This is a comment";`

`NumericValue = 123456;`

What I am trying to accomplish is to capture the string value from the left of the equals sign as one group and the value after the equals sign as a second group. The semicolon should never be included.

The caveat is that if the second group is a string, the quotes from each end must not be included in that capture group.

The expected results would be:

1. Comment = "This is a comment";
  - key group => Comment
  - value group => This is a comment
2. NumericValue = 123456;
  - key group => NumericValue
  - value group => 123456

The following is what I have so far.  This works fine for capturing the numeric value, but leaves the end double quote when capturing the string value.

`(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?:[\"]?)(?<group>.+(?:(?=[\"]?;)))`

**EDIT**

When applying the regex against a string value, it must allow capture of semicolons and double quotes within the string and ignore only the closing ones.

So, if we have an input of:

`Comment = "This is a "comment"; This is still a comment";`

The second capture group should be:

`This is a "comment"; This is still a comment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited based on comment to include `;` and `"` in the comments as per the examples given:

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?:[\"]?)(?<value>((")(?!;?$)|;(?!$)|[^;"])+)"?;?$
```

The following one additionally doesn't allow `;` or `"` to appear in the numeric text. However, to include this, I had to rename the capturing groups because the name cannot be used for more than one group.

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*((?:")(?<valueT>((")(?!;?$)|;(?!$)|[^;"])+)";?$|(?<valueN>[^;"]+);?$)
```

Here is a class that tests it.

For readability, I have separated the `key` and `value` regexes in the class. I have added the test cases in a method within the class. **However, this still doesn't handle the case of a numeric text containing `;` or `"`.** Also, the line needs to be trimmed before being subjected to the pattern test (which I think is feasible).

```
public class NameValuePairRegex{

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String SPACE = "\\s*";
        String EQ = "=";
        String OR = "|";

        /* The original regex tried by you (for comparison). */
        String orig = "(?<key>\\w+)\\s*=\\s*(?:[\\\"]?)(?<value>.+(?:(?=;)))";

        String key = "(?<key>\\w+)";
        String valuePatternForText = "(?:\")(?<valueT>((\")(?!;?$)|;(?!$)|[^;\"])+)\";?$";
        String valuePatternForNumbers = "(?<valueN>[^;\"]+);?$";
        String p = key + SPACE + EQ + SPACE + "(" + valuePatternForText + OR + valuePatternForNumbers + ")";

        Pattern nvp = Pattern.compile( p );
        System.out.println( nvp.pattern() );
        print( input(), nvp );
    }

    private static void print( List<String> input, Pattern ep ) {
        for( String e : input ) {
            System.out.println( e );
            Matcher m = ep.matcher( e );
            boolean found = m.find();
            if( !found ) {
                System.out.println( "\t\tNo match" );
                continue;
            }

            String valueT = m.group( "valueT" );
            String valueN = m.group( "valueN" );

            System.out.print( "\t\t" + m.group( "key" ) + " -> " + ( valueT == null ? "" : valueT ) + " " + ( valueN == null ? "" : valueN ) );
            System.out.println(  );
        }

    }

    private static List<String> input(){
        List<String> neg = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.addAll( neg, 
                "Comment = \"This is a comment\";",
                "Comment = \"This is a comment with semicolon ;\";", 
                "Comment = \"This is a comment with semicolon ; and quote\"\";",
                "Comment = \"This is a comment\"", 
                "Comment = \"This is a \"comment\"; This is still a comment\";",
                "NumericValue = 123456;",
                "NumericValue = 123;456;",
                "NumericValue = 123\"456;",
                "NumericValue = 123456" );

        return neg;
    }

}
```

---

**Original answer:**

The following changed regex is fulfilling the requirements you mentioned. I added the exclusion of `;` and `"` from the value part.

Original that you tried:

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?:[\"]?)(?<group>.+(?:(?=[\"]?;)))
```

The changed one:

```
(?<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?:[\"]?)(?<value>[^;"]+)
```

Comment: This fails if there is either a semicolon or double quote within the string.

Comment: How is the double quote within the string expected to be escaped? Using a ```\```?

Comment: Sree, the input strings are read into memory from a file and are parsed into a string array splitting on the newline.  Each item in that array is run through the regex to get the key/value pairs which are added to a HashMap for later use

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it fits my requirements without the need to modify any other code.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use an alternation where you would have to check for group 2 or group 3:

```
(?<key>\w+)\h*=\h*(?:"(.*?)"|([^"\r\n]+));$
```

- `(?<key>\w+)` Group `key` match 1+ word chars
- `\h*=\h*` Match an `=` between optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `"(.+?)"` Capture in group 2 1+ times any char between `"`

  - `|` Or
  - `([^"\r\n]+)` Capture group 3, match 1+ times any char except `"` or a newline
- `);` Close non capturing group and match `;`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CH6hMb/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<key>\\w+)\\h*=\\h*(?:\"(.*?)\"|([^\"\\r\\n]+));$";
```

Comment: This fails if there is a semicolon within the body of the string

Comment: One option is to use an alternation where you would have to check for group 2 or group 3 `(?<key>\w+)\h*=\h*(?:"(.*?)"|([^"\r\n]+));$` as I don't think you can use the same groups names twice in Java. https://regex101.com/r/zAPL7p/1

Comment: @mikeagoff Perhaps this would be a better pattern if the last match is ok `(?<key>\w+)\h*=\h*("?)(?<group>[^"\r\n]*(?:"(?!;$)[^"\r\n]*)*)\2;`  https://regex101.com/r/oUfLjo/1

Comment: That still doesn't work since the last match in your example fails.

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions are fun, but look how clean and easy to read this would be without using a regular expression:

```
int equals = s.indexOf('=');

String key = s.substring(0, equals).trim();

String value = s.substring(equals + 1).trim();
if (value.endsWith(";")) {
    value = value.substring(0, value.length() - 1).trim();
}
if (value.startsWith("\"") && value.endsWith("\"")) {
    value = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
}
```

Don’t assume that because this uses more lines of code than a regular expression that it’s slower.  The lines of code executed internally by a regex engine will far exceed the above code.

Comment: I specifically asked for a Regex.

Comment: And if I were reviewing your code in a professional setting, I would reject it for using a regex where a regex isn’t warranted.  But if you insist on using a regex, feel free to accept another answer.  I posted this so future readers will at least be aware that regex isn’t always the best solution.

Comment: And that is why you wouldn't work for the same company as me. Sometimes you should ask more questions before assuming anything. And your way is not necessarily better than the Regex just because you assume it is.  Trust me, I hate regexes.  But in this case, there is a requirement for it because of the reuse of the code depending on the element being parsed.  The regex is passed as a string into a method and this is only one of many used.  I am not rewriting the codebase, simply updating what is already there to accept yet another input format.